# New to Jquery and JS: Trying to have the corresponding prices show up with the total

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm very new to JQuery and JS and coding in general unfortunately, and I need help with getting the prices to show up in the adjacent text boxes. Additionally I need help getting the total at the end as well.

The part here that is really confusing to me is that I need to have the third box (SV and prog) dropdown be dependent on the Lens Mat dropdown. If I didn't have that component, doing the prices would be easier with the code that I'm using.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. I skimmed through W3 coding for JS and jquery, but I'm having trouble finding material related to what I need. Any reference material is also really appreciated, as I would like to learn more since I'm trying to teach myself how to code.

```
<body>
<script>
function calculate(){



</script>


<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    dropdowns = {
        web: [
            {desc: "SV", price: 89},
            {desc: "Prog F", price: 190},
            {desc: "Prog O", price: 375},
            {desc: "Prog N", price: 710},
            {desc: "Prog J", price: 58},
            {desc: "Prog K", price: 56},
        ],
        art: [{desc: 'SV', price: 7.00},
              {desc: 'Prog F', price: 32.00},
              {desc: 'Prog O', price: 8.00},
              {desc: 'Prog N', price: 37.00},
              {desc: 'Prog J', price: 9.00},
              {desc: 'Prog K', price: 40.00},
              ],
        blog: [{desc: 'SV', price: 10},
               {desc: 'Prog F', price: 12},
               {desc: 'Prog O', price: 14},
               {desc: 'Prog N', price: 47},
               {desc: 'Prog J', price: 55},
               {desc: 'Prog K', price: 63}
              ],
        press: [{desc: 'SV', price: 27},
                {desc: 'Prog F', price: 37},
                {desc: 'Prog O', price: 47},
                {desc: 'Prog J', price:57},
                {desc: 'Prog K', price:67}
               ]
    }



    populateSelect();

    $(function () {
        $('#cat').change(populateSelect);
    });

    function populateSelect() {
        var cat = $('#cat').val();
        $('#item').empty();

        dropdowns[cat].forEach(function(item) {
            $('#item').append($('<option/>', {
                value: item.price,
                text: item.desc+' = $'+item.price
            }));
        });
    }

});
</script>

<form name="test" method="post" action="check.php">
    <p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #800000;"><strong><span style="font-size: x-large; font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">Order Form</span>
        </strong>
        </span>
    </p>&nbsp;
    <table style="text-align: left; width: 100%; webkit-border-radius: 10px; -moz-border-radius: 10px; border-radius: 10px;" border="0" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="2">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 13.5px; font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;" rowspan="1" colspan="2">Personal Information:
                    <hr />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: right; width: 200px; font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13.5px;">Name :</td>
                <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 500px;">
                    <input style="height: 28px; width: 220px;" type="text" name="name" /> <span style="color: #ff0000;">*</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: right; width: 200px; font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13.5px;">Email :</td>
                <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 500px;">
                    <input style="height: 28px; width: 220px;" type="text" name="email" /><span style="color: #ff0000;"> *</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 13.5px; font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;" rowspan="1" colspan="2">Receipt:
                    <hr />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: right; width: 200px; font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13.5px;">Exam:</td>
            <td><select id="Exam" onchange="calculate()">
<option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" hidden="" value="">Choose Exam Co-pay</option>
<option value="0">Copay 0</option>
<option value="5">Copay 5</option>
<option value="10">Copay 10</option>
<option value="15">Copay 15</option>
<option value="20">Copay 20</option>
<option value="25">Copay 25</option>
<option value="129">Exam full price</option>
</select>
<td><input id=exam_price size="8" value="0" type="text">
            </tr>
            <tr>

                <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: right; width: 200px; font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13.5px;">Lens Mat :</td>
                <td>
                    <select name="cat" id="cat">
                        <option value="web">CR-39 </option>
                        <option value="art">Polycarbonate</option>
                        <option value="blog">1.60</option>
                        <option value="press">1.67</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
<td> <input id="item.price" size="8" value="0" type="text">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
                <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: right; width: 200px; font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13.5px;">SV or Progressive :</td>
                <td>
                    <select name="item" id="item"></select>
                </td>
                <td> <input id="item.price" size="8" value="0" type="text">
</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: right; width: 200px; font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13.5px;">AR:</td>
            <td><select id="AR" onchange="calculate()">
<option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" hidden="" value="">Choose AR</option>
<option value="0">No AR</option>
<option value="37"> A</option>
<option value="61">B</option>
<option value="71">C</option>
<option value="85">D</option>
</select>
</td>
 <td> <input id="item.price" size="8" value="0" type="text">
</td>

<tr>
<td>
</td>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
</td>
<td>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: right; width: 200px; font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13.5px;">Total:</td>
<td>
</td>
<td><input id="total_price" size="8" value="0" type="text"> <br>
</tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</form>

</html>
```

Comment: Pasting a wall of code saying "help me" will not actually help you understand anything. If you are really new to coding as you say, I'd suggest you to start with something simpler, rather than diving face first into advanced libraries like jQuery and trying to build sophisticated interactive web pages all at once.

Comment: Trying to finish this project for the office I currently work at as a kind of parting gift before I leave for grad school. I totally agree with your point, but I only have a week left before I leave.

Comment: Put the script in its own file to get proper tooling. Your code is a mess. And use a formatter ffs!

Comment: `function calculate(){` is wrong no closing brackets

Answer (score 0):

I try to understand your design and I have few questions upon your problem:

What are the formula or what kind of total u would want to see? (I have no idea which to be added or multiplied)
There are more than one (*which is 3 if note mistaken*) same id name called `item.price` which in my acknowledgement it the id name should be **unique**

And as one of your mentioned problem is to show the corresponding value upon the select box (*if I interpret your question correctly*) below is the sample code:

```
$('#Exam').on('change',function(){
    $('#exam_price').val($(this).val());
})
```

I am trying to help you as a beginner of web developer too :)